# Android Support Library ActionBar NullPointerException on version 2.2 (level 8) - conflict with preferences.xml

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library, android-maven-plugin

I am using the v7 Support Library to show an ActionBar on Android 2.x.

When I deploy the app to the device in my IDE (Intellij IDEA) the app works fine.

When I build and package the app to be deployed to the Play Store using maven, I find that I get the following exception when I install and run the packaged app on my device and the app crashes. (It fails on the v8 simulator too). It works fine in both scenarios on android v4.3.

Any idea why this would be crashing when built with maven?

```
01-07 15:05:22.671      937-937/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.triopsis.as.mobile.android/com.triopsis.as.mobile.android.activity.MainMenuActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:677)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:180)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:134)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
        at com.triopsis.as.mobile.android.activity.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:218)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:677)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:180)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:134)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
        at com.triopsis.as.mobile.android.activity.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onFinishInflate(ActionBarView.java:1301)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:218)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:677)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:180)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:134)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
        at com.triopsis.as.mobile.android.activity.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have the following dependencies in maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.0_r3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>19.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>19.0.1</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v13</artifactId>
        <version>19.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the following maven-android-plugin configured:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>14</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**UPDATE**

It has taken a while, but I have discovered that when I have the res/xml/preferences.xml file with PreferenceScreen settings then it causes this crash. If I remove this file, then it does not crash.
Anyone know why that could cause this issue?

Comment: Maybe your maven install does not embedded the support library ?

Comment: How would I see if it has correctly embedded?

Comment: I'm not a Maven-master, but do you have a  `<dependency>` tag with some `support-vXX` artifactID ?

Comment: yes. See updated original post.

Comment: When I list the contents of the apk file I see files in the res folder that are from the v7 support library.

Comment: Okay, and during the build, there's no problem with all these support libs ? Why have you 2 v7 and the v4, which is included in the v13 ?

Comment: BTW, can you try ti change your support dependancy like explain in this [link](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) (replace "compatibility" with "support"). Maybe you can see with a non "appcompat" v7 dependency too?

Comment: I'm afraid none of these suggestions make any difference to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you abslutely need features of `android-maven-plugin` version `3.8.2`? It seems to be bugy.

A similar problem appeared in our project after updating `android-maven-plugin` from version `3.8.0` to `3.8.2`.

Falling back to version `3.8.0` solved the problem.

**Symptoms:**
Our conclusion is that the problem was in the linking of the apklib, all ressources (layouts, drawables...) referenced seemed to be disaligned. For example a layout or a drawable was displayed instead of another. Application was crashing when accessing to a missing reference/id in a layout (the reference was not present because the wrong layout was loaded).

See issue http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=441

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! I will regress the version and check if I still have the issue. From your link, it Looks like the problem might be resolved in the upcoming 3.8.3 version.

Comment: Yes, we regressed to 3.8.0 because this is what we had in our previously tested version but the problem don't seem to be present in 3.8.1 and I saw in maven-android-plugin issues list that they are working on it.

Comment: Thanks worked for me, would of taken a while for me to isolate the problem to maven, thanks again.