# How to use resource in Android library dependency on ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, adt, google-play-services

My development environment:

- adt:22.3.0
- android-maven-plugin:3.8.2
- maven:3.1.1

I am developing a google map Android app with maven structure and dependencies as below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>13.0.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.30</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

I tried apk and aar type but I still can't use resource drawable, string etc (R.drawable.poi, R.style.button_style1..) in android lib dependency. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To use the resource drawables of Library, you also have to import the project into eclipse workspace and reference it from your mavenized project.

I faced this problem, solved it by importing Google-play-services project to workspace and referencing it from my maven project.

For referencing. right click on your project->Properties->Android->(libraryProjects->Add->[browse google-play-library project]), click on apply and save it.

you can find google-play-library project in sdk/extras/google/

Comment: i already know this, i used maven and aar is because dependcy managment without importing dependecy libs into my workspace just declare them in pom.xml. AFAIK maven android plugin support aar package format since 3.8.2(https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog) and we can use resources in android lib files. i achieve this in android studio using maven but not in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem appeared in our project after updating `android-maven-plugin` from version 3.8.0 to `3.8.2`, android-maven-plugin looks bugy.

We had to fallback to version `3.8.0`. I recommend you to do the same using apklib as aar is only available since version 3.8.2 and in case you want to use `aar`to wait for later version of android-maven-plugin.

In details, the problem was in the linking of the apklib, all ressources (layouts, drawables...) referenced seemed to be disaligned. For example a layout or a drawable was displayed instead of another. Application was crashing when accessing to a missing reference/id in a layout (the reference was not present because the wrong layout was loaded).

See issue http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=441

Comment: in fact my problem is related eclipe-maven plugin integration, thanks your point, unfortunately android maven plugin still looks buggy

Comment: Have you tried android-maven-plugin 3.9.0-rc1? Changelog: https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog